# Forcing apps to install/download on SD

Tags: internal-storage, 4.1-jelly-bean

I have a HTC Desire, which has a limited space in the phone. Therefore I want to make all apps install to the SD card by default.

However, I can't make it work. I have tried the `pm set-install-location 2` command, and I can also confirm that it is set to 2, but I still can't download apps that takes more space than available.

I have it rooted, and installed 4.1.2 on it.

Comment: What apps are you trying to install on SD card?

Comment: You need to install data2sd or similar. If you're using sandvold's or evervolv's ROM then in terminal type su, after that,  a2sd install, give answer y,n,y to the questions that follow.

Comment: @roxan I am actually using Evervolv's ROM. When I do that, it just states that `/sd-ext` is not mounted properly, yada yada, `Did you partition your sdcard correctly?` - I havent partitioned it at all.

Comment: You need to partition your SD card, check Google on how to partition SD card for data2sd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have Evervolv's rom I assume you have a custom recovery. Backup all the files on your sd card. Boot to recovery and partition your sd card. I would suggest at 1GB for sd ext.

Answer (score 1):

This will only allow you to install apps automatically onto the SD card if:

1. They have set the app to install onto the SD card 'Auto'
2. They allow you to install onto the SD card

Most likely, the app(s) you are trying to download does not have an auto setting for SD card install, and it cannot be installed onto the SD card.